# Watch variable in Eclipse + Sequoyah in android

Tags: android, eclipse

How to watch variable in C++ (android native code)?
I am using Eclipse + Sequoyah  plug-in

Answer (score 0):

New ADT plugin supporting native code development. Window->Preferences->Android tree under you see NDK topic than select this and right window set Android Native Development Location apply than.

Project right click AndroidTools->AddNativeSupport then click OK.

Comment: How does that fix my problem?

Comment: This tool get eclipse perspective